# Modify the program to accept a telephone number with any number of letters.

Tags: java

Modify the program to accept a telephone number with any number of letters. The output should display a hyphen after the first 3 digits and subsequently a hyphen (-) after every four digits. Also, modify the program to process as many telephone numbers as the user wants.

Below is what i have to edit.

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

String telephone_letter;
int index;




System.out.print("Enter Telephone letters : ");
telephone_letter = keyboard.nextLine();
char aChar[] = telephone_letter.toCharArray();
int[] number = new int[100];
for(index=0;index<telephone_letter.length();index++){


    switch (aChar[index]) 
    {
        case 'A':
        case 'a':
        case 'B':
        case 'b':
        case 'C':
        case 'c':
            number[index] = 2;
            break;
        case 'D':
        case 'd':
        case 'E':
        case 'e':
        case 'F':
        case 'f':
            number[index] = 3;
            break;
        case 'G':
        case 'g':
        case 'H':
        case 'h':
        case 'I':
        case 'i':
            number[index] = 4;
            break;
        case 'J':
        case 'j':
        case 'K':
        case 'k':
        case 'L':
        case 'l':
            number[index] = 5;
            break;
        case 'M':
        case 'm':
        case 'N':
        case 'n':
        case 'O':
        case 'o':
            number[index] = 6;
            break;
        case 'P':
        case 'p':
        case 'Q':
        case 'q':
        case 'R':
        case 'r':
        case 'S':
        case 's':
            number[index] = 7;
            break;
        case 'T':
        case 't':
        case 'U':
        case 'u':
        case 'V':
        case 'v':
            number[index] = 8;
            break;
        case 'W':
        case 'w':
        case 'X':
        case 'x':
        case 'Y':
        case 'y':
        case 'Z':
        case 'z':
            number[index] = 9;
            break;
        default:
            break;


    }

}

System.out.println("=======================================");
System.out.println("The Telephone letter is : " + telephone_letter);
System.out.println("The Phone number is     : " + number[0]+number[1]+number[2]+"-"+number[3]+number[4]+number[5]+number[6]);
System.out.println("=======================================");  

}
```

This part is what i tried.

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

String telephone_letter;
int index;




System.out.print("Enter Telephone letters : ");
telephone_letter = keyboard.nextLine();
char aChar[] = telephone_letter.toCharArray();
int[] number = new int[100];

while(telephone_letter !="2")
{
for(index=0;index<telephone_letter.length();index++){


    switch (aChar[index]) 
    {
        case 'A':
        case 'a':
        case 'B':
        case 'b':
        case 'C':
        case 'c':
            number[index] = 2;
            break;
        case 'D':
        case 'd':
        case 'E':
        case 'e':
        case 'F':
        case 'f':
            number[index] = 3;
            break;
        case 'G':
        case 'g':
        case 'H':
        case 'h':
        case 'I':
        case 'i':
            number[index] = 4;
            break;
        case 'J':
        case 'j':
        case 'K':
        case 'k':
        case 'L':
        case 'l':
            number[index] = 5;
            break;
        case 'M':
        case 'm':
        case 'N':
        case 'n':
        case 'O':
        case 'o':
            number[index] = 6;
            break;
        case 'P':
        case 'p':
        case 'Q':
        case 'q':
        case 'R':
        case 'r':
        case 'S':
        case 's':
            number[index] = 7;
            break;
        case 'T':
        case 't':
        case 'U':
        case 'u':
        case 'V':
        case 'v':
            number[index] = 8;
            break;
        case 'W':
        case 'w':
        case 'X':
        case 'x':
        case 'Y':
        case 'y':
        case 'Z':
        case 'z':
            number[index] = 9;
            break;
        default:
            break;



    }

}

System.out.println("=======================================");
System.out.println("The Telephone letter is : " + telephone_letter);
System.out.println("The Phone number is     : " + number[0]+number[1]+number[2]+"-"+number[3]+number[4]+number[5]+number[6]);
System.out.println("=======================================");  

System.out.print("Enter Telephone letters : ");
telephone_letter = keyboard.nextLine();



}
```

My output is wrong.

```
Enter Telephone letters : fewfwef
======================================
The Telephone letter is : fewfwef
The Phone number is     : 339-3933
=======================================
Enter Telephone letters : wsqsq
=======================================
The Telephone letter is : wsqsq
The Phone number is     : 339-3933
=======================================
```

And another Question is how do i do this `The output should display a hyphen after the first 3 digits and subsequently a hyphen (-) after every four digits.`

Comment: You will find `ARRAY.length` a valuable tool here.

Comment: @ken yeo This looks like a school work from Kaplan Diploma. Are you from Singapore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a homework problem so here are some hints to help you solve it yourself.

(1) Using a fixed number like 100 is rarely a good idea:

```
int[] number = new int[aChar.length];
```

(2) The scanner can tell you if there is more to be scanned(read):

```
Scanner keyboard  = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter Telephone letters : ");
while (keyboard.hasNextLine()) {
        String telephone_letter = keyboard.nextLine();
        ...
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Enter Telephone letters : ");
}
```

(3) A loop is good for counting.  If the first count is different, then start different:

```
            int todash = 3;
            System.out.print("The Phone number is     : ");
            for (int i=0; i < number.length; ++i) {
                    if (todash == 0) {
                            System.out.print("-");
                            todash = 4;
                    }
                    System.out.print(number[i]);
                    --todash;
            }
            System.out.println("");
```

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten you're code. It may be easier to work with.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Telephone {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter Telephone letters : ");
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();

        TelephoneProcessor telephoneProcessor = new TelephoneProcessor(input);
        String result = telephoneProcessor.proccess();

        System.out.println("=======================================");
        System.out.println("The Telephone letter is : " + input);
        System.out.println("The Phone number is     : " + result);
        System.out.println("=======================================");

    }

}

class TelephoneProcessor {

    Map<String, String> matches = new HashMap<>();
    String toProcess;

    public TelephoneProcessor(String toProcess) {
        this.toProcess = toProcess;
        matches.put("[a-c]", "2");
        matches.put("[d-f]", "3");
        matches.put("[g-i]", "4");
        matches.put("[j-l]", "5");
        matches.put("[m-o]", "6");
        matches.put("[p-r]", "7");
        matches.put("[s-w]", "8");
        matches.put("[x-z]", "9");
    }
    public String proccess() {

        if(toProcess != "2") {
            matches.forEach((regex, replacement) -> {
                toProcess = toProcess.replaceAll(regex, replacement);
            });
        }

        return toProcess.substring(0,3) + "-" + toProcess.substring(3,7);
    }
}
```

It only asks once but that's easy to solve by making a class that contains the main method in a method and loops it.

I hope this helps for further extensions of the program :)

Comment: Feel free to edit to cover the questions but I'm short on time right now.. I'll come back later.